# Alternate Way of Computing Complex Polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm computing the value of this polynomial:

$$\left(\frac{2}{z}+\frac{z}{2}\right)^2+2$$

Where $z = -1 + \sqrt{3}i$

I converted to polar $z = 4e^{i5\pi/6}$ to grind out the first term then converted back to cartesian so I could add. I was wondering if there was a faster way of simplifying this expression. I ask because its a question on an old timed exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:   note that $\,\dfrac{z}{2}\,$ is a complex cube root of unity, and $\,\dfrac{2}{z}\,$ its conjugate.

Comment: okay I see that now, how did you see that? I wasn't even looking for that.

Comment: @yoshi Once you've seen $\,e^{i \pi /4}=(1+i)/\sqrt{2}\,$, or $\,e^{i 2 \pi /3} = (-1 + i \sqrt{3})/2\,$ a few times, you'll tend to recognize them.

Comment: Also note $z/2$ and $2/z$ are complex cube root of unity. So $z/2 +2/z=-1$

Comment: @LoopBack Right, $\,z/2+2/z=z/2+\overline{z/2}=2 \operatorname{Re}(z/2)\,$.

Answer (score 1):

$$z = -1 + \sqrt{3}i=2e^{i2\pi /3} $$
It depends on how experienced you are in working with polar forms of complex numbers.

Comment: Aye - ya I bungled the conversion too