# Practice with Complex Polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers

I'm looking for some exercises in manipulating complex polynomials and roots of unity. Problems like this:
[Alternate Way of Computing Complex Polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935047/alternate-way-of-computing-complex-polynomial)

Do people know of a good place to find some?

Comment: The following [link](http://www.baileyworldofmath.org/uploads/Schaums-outline-complex-variables.pdf) is a pdf for Schaums Complex Variables, and there should be a wealth of problems in there

Comment: My suggestion: in most cases you don’t want to use the polar representation. But what kind of manipulation? What do you want to do with the roots of unity?

Comment: math gre practice